# How would I go about making a RewriteRule as described?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a RewriteRule for my site (.htaccess), and what I wish to do is to rewrite the page URLs as follows:

*www.domain.com/p/pagename*

should rewrite to

*www.domain.com/pagename.php*

I assume I would use regex to detect the /p/ and rewrite it, but I tried already, and I have not been able to create something that works. Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^p/(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple rewrite like

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*) /$1
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: That works, but I am choosing @anubhava's solution :)

Thanks anyways!